# AVPlayerViewController as a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using following code to play a vimeo(Used a parser to extract mp4 url and feed it to AVPlayerController) video using AVPlayerController. Here playerContainerView is a view I am using in my viewController.

```
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: vimeoURL)
self.playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
self.playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer?.player = avPlayer
self.playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer?.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .new, context: nil)
self.addChildViewController(playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer!)
self.playerContainerView.addSubview(playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer!.view)
playerContainerView.vimeoPlayer?.view.frame = CGRect(x: zeroOriginX, y: zeroOriginY, width: self.playerContainerView.frame.size.width, height: self.playerContainerView.frame.size.height)
```

Is it necessary here to add AVPLayerController as childViewController? If I comment this line, my player still works! So should I use addChildViewController() method?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found that this actually solved a problem I ran into on my project.  I wasn't able to get my player controls to show up without calling `addChildViewController`.  Once I did, they showed up.  So if anyone out there is having issues getting their player controls to show when you're adding the AVPlayerViewController as a subview, make sure you call `addChildViewController`.